# design of C++ iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working with a legacy API that has to be called like this:

```
Iterator iter = IteratorCreate();
while (iter)
{
    Object obj = IteratorGet(iter);

    //do stuff

    IteratorNext(iter);
}
IteratorDelete(iter);
```

I was wondering if I could wrap it into c++ iterators, so after googling a bit I saw that I could build something like this:

```
class MyIterator {
public:
    MyIterator(int id)
    {
        m_iter = IteratorCreate();
        m_obj = IteratorGet(m_iter);
        std::cout << m_obj << " enhanced " << this << std::endl;
    }

    MyIterator()
    {
        std::cout << m_obj << " default " << this << std::endl;
    }

    bool operator!=(const MyIterator& other)
    {
        return (m_obj != other.m_obj);
    }

    const MyIterator& operator++()
    {
        IteratorNext(m_iter);
        m_obj = IteratorGet(m_iter);
        return *this;
    }

    CNeoPersist* operator*()
    {
        if (m_iter)
            return m_obj;
        else
            return nullptr;
    }

    ~MyIterator()
    {
        std::cout << m_iter << " " << this << std::endl;
    }

private:
    CIterator* m_iter = nullptr;
    CNeoPersist* m_obj = nullptr;
};

class MyContainer
{
public:

    MyIterator begin() const { return begin_; }
    MyIterator end() const { return end_; }
    MyContainer(int id) : begin_(id), end_() {}

private:
MyIterator begin_;
MyIterator end_;
};
```

Which seems to kind of work, but I was wondering if there a better way of doing it. Also, while debugging it I saw something "weird", the constructors get called 2 times, but destructors get called 4 times:

```
0000006B27633D98 enhanced 0000006B22DFF858
0000000000000000 default 0000006B22DFF868

0000000000000000 0000006B22DFF8C8
0000006B267FE510 0000006B22DFF898
0000000000000000 0000006B22DFF868
0000006B267FE510 0000006B22DFF858
```

Why is that?

Comment: Basic rule of zero violation.

Comment: If they are copied using the copy constructor that probably accounts for the difference.

Comment: The "wierd"  bit is because you are missing the copy constructor and assignment operators for the new iterator class.  Read rule of three and rule of zero

Comment: If the wrapped container can contain duplicate elements, `operator!=` is wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't the end_ object be a different state than begin_ ?

Comment: Adding to everything which is being said, it puzzles me to see how underlying iterator is dereferenced and it's object copied on every operation! I would expect this to happen only when wrapper iterator is dereferenced.

Comment: @ SergeyA me too :) There is no value to this exercise if the iterator that results cannot be used with std::find (the representative of a lot of other algorithms). The code for using the legacy API as is is not that ugly. Maybe some RAII would be valuable (pace @Puppy) instead of implementing an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic rule of zero violation. It occurred because instead of re-using resource handling components from the Standard library that do this job properly, you wrote your own incorrect resource handling.

A simple example is what happens if the iterator is copied, which the Standard requires that it must be able to handle.

You should implement virtually all resource handling in terms of the Standard library primitives. A simple shared pointer would trivially solve this issue.

Comment: The 'Iterator' might not be a pointer and therefore not suitable as the argument of shared_ptr.

Comment: Doesn't need to be a pointer. Worst comes to worst, you can just `shared_ptr<unique_ptr<T, freaky_deleter>>`.

Comment: @Puppy how would you wrap that API then?